# How to display non ascii words or character in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, html

The logical error is that the php doesn't display the desired output for pronunciation. eg. the desired output is \ə-ˈchēv\ but this one \?-?ch?v\ is displayed in the browser.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $out .= "English word: " .$row['word_en'] . "<br>";
        $out .= "Pronunciation: " .$row['pronunciation'] . "<br>";
        $out .= "Grammar: " .$row['grammar'] . "<br>";
        $out .= "Definition: ".'<div style="width:600px; border:0px solid orange; margin-left: 90px; word-wrap:break-word; margin-top: -19px;">'. $row['definition'] . "</div>";

        //iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $out), PHP_EOL; //displays error

        echo $out;
    }
```

Comment: By the way, plain mysql extenaion is deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo instead. It will offers you some new features such as prepared statements

Comment: I can't because I already started in the deprecated mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

to your browser HTML code

Comment: I already added that but still it doesn't work. Why oh why? I think the problem is with the php.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with MySQL. Please check, which collation is used

1. In connection (PHP code connecting to mysql)
2. In database
3. In tables
4. In columns

These can have different collations.

(mysql replaces characters it doesn't know with question marks)

Comment: I changed the  character set to utf8 and collation to utf8_general_ci. The output works good in navicat mysql but not in php.

Comment: And what collation you use on database connection? @Judo100

Comment: $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dictionary"). none

Comment: <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>. I added the header but still it doesn't work.

Comment: After connection do query "SET NAMES utf8"

Comment: Other note: utf8 in mysql is crippled. It cannot store fourbyte characters. You should use utf8mb4 instead.

Comment: And are you sure that collation in columns is also utf8?

Comment: only 1 column is utf8.

Comment: You probably want store data in all columns in utf8, right?

Comment: I mean only one is utf8 for the pronunciation column and I just want that to be displayed properly in php.

Comment: Have you added SET NAMES query? I highly recommend having everything in modern encoding UTF-8